# Term for the type of audible reaction typically written as "heh" or "hmph"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

Is there a term for a person's audible reaction, the quoted written form of which we typically find spelled as ***heh*** or ***hmph***?

Comment: This would be as opposed to "hmmm" which is more a reaction of wondering or pondering. (e.g. *"Hmmm", I pondered*)

Comment: *Hmph* isn't really "as opposed to" *Hmmm*. The latter is often just a more "deferential" way of saying *I don't [wholeheartedly] agree*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think they express different sentiments (and thus call for different words).

*Heh* (a slight laugh) could be described as a **[chuckle](http://www.onelook.com/?w=chuckle&ls=a)**.

*Hmph* (a sound of disapproval) could be described as a **[harrumph](http://www.onelook.com/?w=harrumph&ls=a)**.

Comment: +1 for *harrumph*, which I think is fine both as a noun and a verb. I think OP didn't mean *Heh* as in a chuckle - the *harrumph* context can indicated by lots of onomatopoeic variations, including *Heh, Hum, Hah, Hmph*, etc. They're all vague though - I think anything implying disapproval/exasperation is covered by *harrumph* even if the actual sound is transcribed as *Tut, Tsk, Pffft*, or whatever.

Comment: Hrm. Yeah, I guess I use the textual "heh" more as a reaction meaning "that's interesting" moreso than as a chuckle, but it does make sense in that respect. My wife also suggests **scoffing** as an alternative term for "hmph" which admittedly sounds better as a verb than saying (e.g. "Hmph", I scoffed.)

Answer (score 2):

I think the word you're looking for is "onomatopoeia".

Comment: "Well, you can't exactly use it as a verb. Heh." I onomatopoeiaed.

Comment: While *heh* or *hmph* is correctly an onomatopoeia, I think the OP is looking more for a word like "sighed" that is relevant to the specific case.

Answer (score 1):

A female friend who was baffled about why her husband wasn't having some minor health problem seen to said

> *I told him he needed to go see the doctor.*

I suggested that he had

> *responded with an **inarticulate grunt***

She agreed and was--perhaps--enlightened. At least she bullied him into giving a *real* response and eventually into seeing the doctor.

Anyway, it's not a single word or a particularly sonorous phrase, but I think it covers the whole category. Learning to interpret the ones *your* SO uses is a whole different problem.